# Where are microinstructions stored after decoded from machine instructions?

Tags: cpu-architecture, microprocessors

For CISC-architechture processors, machine instructions are decoded into microinstructions and then executed. So after decoding and before being executed, where will those microinstructions be stored? Is there a dedicated register or storage inside the CPU to hold them?

Comment: It depends. Do you have any specific microarchitecture in mind?

Comment: Say the Intel x86 architechture, if you need a more specific one maybe Pentium 4 or Haswell?

Comment: See the links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), esp. David Kanter's [Haswell](http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/) and Sandybridge (linked from that) and earlier writeups.  Agner Fog's microarchitecture guide is also excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like some of the comments already suggested - it depends on the microarchitecture.

However, to give you a general answer for an out of order processor - after decode and before execution - instruction wait in the reservation stations for the operands to be ready.

Look at this wiki page for details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservation_station